# GitHub - expand all search results in a file by default

Tags: github, search

I'm talking about basically autoclicking these on any search results
page like [this one](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ath-ch%2Fyoutube-music%20backend&type=code):

[image: GitHub expand file search results button]

I there any setting for this that I missed or is a userscript needed?